# How to run a .vbs file on a specific user profile present on a remote windows server?

Tags: command-line, qtp

Here's the scenario:
I have one remote windows server which has 2 user profiles currently logged in. I want to run a .vbs file remotely on a specific user profile on that windows server. This is what I am doing right now but it doesnt work! In command line, I am doing `RunAs /profile /user:Domain_Name\User_Name "cScript.exe path_of_vbs"`

It gives me the following error: **Unable to run - cscript.exe path_of_vbs. Login failure: unknown user name or bad password**

Is it just the credentials or am I missing something more? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use psexec , e.g. like this example:

```
psexec \\computername -u domain\user -p password "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" http:\\223.100.200.78
```

I think with the RunAs you also have to give the password for the user.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx there you can read about psexec and the install. You first have to install (copy) it to the directory of the executable files.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! Actually I was entering the wrong domain name. My initial command RunAs is working!